# How to call functions using Python Arrow Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to call functions using self and arrow syntax (forgive me I don't know the technical term). I would look to return the value of another function from main but I can't seem to figure out the correct implementation.

I tried passing self as an argument but I got `self not defined` as a different error.

```py
class Solution:
    def return_address(self, address: str) -> str:
        return self.address

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print(return_address('Hello World'))
```

I expect the return_address() function to return 'Hello World' but instead I am given the following error: `TypeError: return_address() missing 1 required positional argument: 'address'`. Isn't the address argument already provided, why does the interpreter say it is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address

    def return_address(self) -> str:
        return self.address

if __name__ == "__main__":
   sol = Solution('Hello World')
   print(sol.return_address())
```

Comment: I tried that but the error I get is ```NameError: name 'self' is not defined```

Comment: @Ryan I showed the whole solution , this should work.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code your provided answers the question.